# derive private keys that have been xored whith each other to a public key

Tags: cryptography, runtime, xor, encryption-asymmetric

## Hello everyone

I have a pool of binary data with *n* elements.
*k* of those elements (the private keys) have been xored with each other, generating another element (a public key), which is also in the pool. All the other elements are irrelevant.

So when xoring the private keys and the public key, the result should be 0.

I don't know the position of the *k* private keys and the position of the public key. I have to figure those out.

What would be an approach I could try, a phrase I could search for or an existing algorithm?

## What I've tried (and failed because of runtime)

Of course I tried the brute force approach.

1. My first attempt was the worst. I made an iterator, and checked every option until I got there.
2. I did the same thing like in the first attempt but with an imaginary tree.

Those worked, but the runtime was to bad, with *n* = 115; *k* = 11.

I've tried something like [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-number-subarrays-given-xor/) but I couldn't get something in this direction work for my needs.

Please help I put way to much time in this,
Hellow2

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7Bk%7D%2Cn%3D105%2C+k%3D11

Comment: You'd probably have to use k = 12 as you're just interested in XORing to zero. You can see the idea behind getting a set of unique elements out of an existing set [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/876309/229184). Of course you can simplify the XOR's by adding and removing values from an existing single value, and this is very much parallelizable as well. But in the end any one key won't leak any information, so you'd have to try many combinations whichever way you look at it, I'd expect around 250 trillion of them, i.e. it is similar to cracking a 47 bit key.

Comment: You could also just look at the first byte(s) to see if they match, presuming the private key  values are reasonably large. A meet in the middle attack might also be feasible, come to think of it.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably it. You can see that if x1 ^x2 ^ x3 ^ x4 = 0 then x1 ^ x2 = x3 ^ x4, that split can be anywhere. I table a table.

Comment: Thanks, the  meet in the middle attack worked :)